# In Shell, how can I make an array of files and how do I use it to then compare it to another file?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, file, piping

How do I make an array of files in shell. Is it just

```
files = (file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt)
```

or is it

```
files = ("file1.txt" "file2.txt" "file3.txt)
```

If later on in the program I want to refer to this array and pick a specific file to read, how would I do that. I am asking because I would like to have a conditional that would read that file and compare it to an output file.

Would I just do: ( I know I can't do this)

```
if grep -q ${outputs[i]} output; then
   #etc.
```

But what should I do instead then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No spaces around `=` in assignments, arrays are no excepetion.

```
files=( file1.txt "file2.txt" )
```

Quotes around file names are needed if file names contain special characters, e.g. whitespace, parentheses, etc.

You can use a `for` loop to walk the array:

```
for file in "${array[@]}" ; do
    if grep -q "$file" output ; then
```

Are you sure you want to use $file as the regular expression? Then you need to handle regex characters specially, i.e. dot, caret, dollar sign, etc.

If you want to compare contents of the two files, use `diff`, not `grep`.

```
if diff -q "$file" output > /dev/null ; then
    echo Same
else
    echo Different
fi
```